# Content Provider with a Default Activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

When using Android'd `ContactsContract`, in the app's activity you create an intent like `Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI)`. This will automatically open an activity from the Contacts Provider.
**How do I create my provider to behave the same way?** Meaning, I want to allow users of my provider to pick some item from my content provider.

Comment: Which Information ur supporting users to pick? can you please elaborate?

Comment: `"This will automatically open an activity from the Contacts Provider"` what do you mean? creating an Intent doesn't open any Activity, let alone Activity from a Content Provider, what actually do you want to achieve?

Comment: @android_dev - I have bank cards stored in the SQLite DB and an activity that displays the list of these cards. Now I want users of my provider to see this activity so they pick a card.

Comment: @pskink - ContactsContract provider starts an activity when in your app you create an intent like `Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI)`. So I want to do the similar feature in my content provider.

Comment: no, ContactsContract provider doesn't start any activity, startActivity() as its name suggests does it

Comment: @pskink:  So, how do I do that in order for the activity to be started when users of my content provider passes the uri, like in CuntactsContract case?

Comment: see http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/intent-filter-element.html and http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/IntentFilter.html